# How to extract english words from a string of hashed values?

Tags: javascript

My web application uses google firestore to upload documents. However, firestore hashes the documents name but I want to extract that name and use it. The formatted string looks like this.

```
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agency-register-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agency-register-documents-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agencyRegister-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agency-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";
```

As you can see, after test/ the file name comes first and before the files type there is a hash and finally the file type which is .png here. How can I get the english words(agency-register, agency-register-documents, agencyRegister, et.) or the file name from these strings? I'm trying to create a dynamic structure.

I don't know the required logic, so I didn't do anything.

Comment: If they're all `some-realWords-gibberish` then split on `-` and throw away the last item. But if you're uploading the documents presumably you have an actual name; seems like you could associate the name with the resulting document earlier in the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a regular expression.

For example:

```js
let pattern = /https:\/\/storage\.googleapis\.com\/test\/([\w-]*)-\w*.png/;
let url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agency-register-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";

let name = url.match(pattern)[1];
```

To see what it does, https://regex101.com/r/7TcJuI/1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to solve it with regular expressions.

You can do it the way suggested in the comment.

```
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/test/agencyRegister-crrRhaUSWopn4QRc2M54MX.png";
const parts = url.split("test/")[1].split("-");
parts.pop();
const result = parts.join("-");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Jazzcat, your solution words perfectly as well. Thanks to both of you.